# Valid short-variable declarations in range unpacking

Tags: go

Why does this code run
    package main

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    myMap := map[string]int{
        "a": 1,
        "b": 1,
    }
    for k, v := range myMap {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}
```

But this code

```
package main

func main() {
    x := test()
}

func test() (int, int) {
    return 0, 1
}
```

won't compile:

```
福 ~/c/p/gobook (f14d0e9)|master⚡
± : go build test.go
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:4: multiple-value test() in single-value context
```

Note that the same holds for arrays and slices:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    myArray := [...]int{1, 2, 3}
    mySlice := myArray[:]
    for i := range mySlice {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
    for i, x := range mySlice {
        fmt.Println(i, x)
    }
    for i := range myArray {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
    for i, x := range myArray {
        fmt.Println(i, x)
    }
}
```

What is the compiler doing that allows consumers to opt-in to unpacking one or both return values in `map` ranges? Why did the language designers allow this for maps, slices, and arrays, but not for return values of functions?

Answer (score 2):

Your program expects that you're going to accept two values returned from function `test`. In fact you're getting only one. To make this code work you need to make only one small change.

```
package main

func main() {
    x,_ := test()
}

func test() (int, int) {
    return 0, 1
}
```

In case of ranges apparently it has multiple interfaces. Please also pay attention to the fact that it is not a function but reserved word. It is impossible to have optional returned parameters for your function - Go doesn't support functions overloading. Unfortunately this is restricted by language (from my perspective it's a good thing that you don't create confusion and you always have only one method with only one specific name that always matches only one interface).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To clarify, I know why the failing example fails; it seems to me that the `range` example should fail for the same reason.

I suppose then that your answer is "`range` has multiple interfaces". And I'd guess that the designers felt the convenience was worth the ambiguity.

Comment: Note that this multiple interface also exists outside of built-in keywords; when accessing a `map`, e.g., you can choose to consume the second variable (indicating whether or not the key is present) or not.